# "remember to do" vs. "remember doing"

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

What is the difference between in the meaning of  these two sentences:

> - I will remember to post the letter.
> - I will remember posting the letter.

How can we know where to use gerund or infinitive?
Are there any specific verbs that can be used particularly for gerund and infinitive separately?

Comment: In the first example, it is an action that has not yet been fulfilled.  The second is foresight of hindsight (which is about as confusing as it sounds) - they know they will look back on the time when they posted the letter.

Comment: Also, your question is a little unclear. What do you mean by 'Are there specific verbs for these?'

Comment: Really Thanks for your response. Can you please elaborate the second example, I didn't get it. I meant to say,  are there any specific verbs that can be used particularly for gerund and infinvite separately?

Comment: At this point, they have not had the experience, but they know that they *will remember* doing it.  For example, 'I will remember doing this for the rest of my life', they haven't done it yet, but they know it will be momentous enough for them to look back on it.  Hope that's clearer!

Comment: Consider editing your question to make it clearer, so people don't have to look through the comments for clarification :)

Comment: Your sentences provide a good example of the difference between gerunds and infinitives. Generally, infinitives are specific to the action of the verb, the doing of it as a thing, and gerunds tend to have a much larger scope of meaning that includes the whole idea surrounding the action of the verb as a thing in general. *I like to swim* is about the action only, where *I like swimming,* could mean actual swimming but could also only mean that the subject is a fan of swimming, and never actually swims.

Comment: Also, I think there may be a mood shift between the sentences, where 1 is indicative and 2 feels subjunctive (but I'm not sure).

Comment: As for the verbs, yes, there are special verbs. ***Every*** verb in English is special, in the sense that it has its own list of requirements, prohibitions, and options. They all have to be learned individually, though they fall together into semantic groups, like the [sense verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96744/15299), which can take any kind of complement, with almost no difference in meaning.

Comment: I am voting to close this question for lack of basic research, and protest its migration to ELL. There is no basic research, and should not be accepted anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> > I will remember to post the letter.
> >     I will remember posting the letter.
>
> How can we know where to use gerund or infinitive? Are there
>   any specific verbs that can be used particularly for gerund and
>   infinvite separately?

It's as already noted above by John Lawler, and Michael Swan says in his Practical English Usage as follows:

> §296
>   **1 verbs that can be followed by -ing forms**
>   It is best to check in a good dictionary.

Roughly, to-infinitives have the sense of *purpose*.

> something you have to do
>   5 [transitive] to not forget to do something; to actually do what you have to do
>   - ***Remember to call*** me when you arrive!
>   ([Oxford Learner's Dictionary | remember](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/remember?q=remember))

The -ing form when used an object usually has more sense of *noun* than the to-infinitive.

> someone or something from the past
>   2 [transitive, intransitive] to have or keep an image in your memory of an event, a person, a place, etc. from the past
>   **remember doing something**
>   - *Do you **remember turning** the lights off before we came out?*
>   ([Oxford Learner's Dictionary | remember](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/remember?q=remember))